# Two or more Many to Many relationships between two tables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two tables:

`Users` and `Groups`

a User has_many groups and a group, has_many a users:

```
u = User.last
u.groups
g = Group.last
g.users
```

Supposed I wanted a second list of different groups, for some strange reason. Where once again a User has may groups (called other_group in this example) and a group has many users.

```
u = User.last
u.other_groups
g = Group.last
g.other_users
```

How do I associate two models in this relationship, twice using Active Record? Do I need multiple has and belongs to many tables? perhaps a has and belongs to many "through". What does this look like?

---

Answer:

```
class Matter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :matters_lawfirms
  has_many :matters_other_lawfirms
  has_many :lawfirms, class_name: 'Lawfirm', through: :matters_lawfirms,  :source => :lawfirm
  has_many :other_lawfirms, class_name: 'Lawfirm', through: :matters_other_lawfirms,  :source => :lawfirm
end

class Lawfirm < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :matters_lawfirms
  has_many :matters_other_lawfirms
  has_many :matters, class_name: 'Matter', through: :matters_lawfirms,  :source => :matter
  has_many :other_matters, class_name: 'Matter', through: :matters_other_lawfirms,  :source => :matter
end

class MattersLawfirm < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :matter
  belongs_to :lawfirm
end

class MattersOtherLawfirm < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :matter
  belongs_to :lawfirm
end
```

migrations:

```
class AddMatterOtherLawfirms < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :matters_other_lawfirms, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :matter, :lawfirm
    end

    add_index :matters_other_lawfirms, [:matter_id, :lawfirm_id],
      name: "matters_other_lawfirms_index",
      unique: true
  end
end



class AddMatterLawfirmsHabtmt < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :matters_lawfirms, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :matter, :lawfirm
    end

    add_index :matters_lawfirms, [:matter_id, :lawfirm_id],
      name: "matters_lawfirms_index",
      unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: can you tell us your relation definitions in your models please?

Comment: Yes. In once instance I have a group of outside counsel and in another I have a group of local counsel. 

These groups of people change from case to case. So the only way this association will work is 2 has and belongs to many associations. I just haven't done this yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already know how to handle has_many relationships in your data model (the point to which Alper appears to be writing), it's quite easy to accomodate multiple relationships between two tables (I do something right now which involves linking users distinctly to a projects on which they are working, and to projects which they own. I believe this is very similar to what you're seeking to accomplish). The code would look something like this:

**User Model**

```
has_many :regular_groups, class_name: 'Group', through: :user_regular_groups
has_many :other_groups, class_name: 'Group', through: :user_other_groups
```

**Group Model**

```
has_many :regular_users, class_name: 'User', through: :user_regular_groups
has_many :other_users, class_name: 'User', through: :user_other_groups
```

Obviously in this case we're using two distinct association tables (user_regular_groups and user_other_groups), but you could accomplish something similar with one using a scope (along the lines of what Alper is recommending).

I hope that helps!

Comment: Hi There Connor, I see this: ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association : user_regular_groups in model Group

Comment: Great this got me on track. The answer is posted above in my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't define many to many relationship using belong_to

You should implement `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many :through` relationship instead of `has_many` - `belongs_to` relationship.

EDIT

Ok i think i get it now,

You can't achive this using a single has_and_belongs_to_many table, i'd go for a has_many :through relation. If you have only two group category, set a flag for that category in your join table.

Not tested yet, but something similar should work

```
class GroupMembership #.. with category field or something
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user

class User
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :local_groups, -> { where group_memberships: { category: 'local' } }, :through => :group_memberships, :source => :group
  has_many :outside_groups, -> { where group_memberships: { category: 'outside' } }, :through => :group_memberships, :source => :group

class Group
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :local_users, -> { where group_memberships: { category: 'local' } }, :through => :group_memberships, :source => :user
  has_many :outside_users, -> { where group_memberships: { category: 'outside' } }, :through => :group_memberships, :source => :user
```

For the HABTM relationship, you need to define more then one join table.

Comment: I made the edit, It was changed from has many to one, to N to N and I failed to update the body. Sorry about that!